# Trying to get followers with user id using twitter python library

Tags: python, twitter

So, I've been trying to get friend list with GetFollowers function using the twitter library.

```
try:
    print "3"
    pos=random.randint(0,len(idList)-1)
    print i
    followersList=self.api.GetFollowers(user_id=i,count=5)
    print followersList
    print "4"
    for x in followersList:
        print str(x.user.followers_count)
        print "addedf " + str(x.user.screen_name)
        if x.user.followers_count>self.minFavoriteReq:
            self.api.CreateFriendship(user_id=x.user.id)
            print "added " + str(x.user.screen_name)


except Exception as e:
    print e
    print "trying to add new follower"
```

I seem to be getting stuck on the function call. No exceptions are being thrown, I just print the "i" then it sits. I'm not sure exactly why it isnt returning, or what I can do to get it to start. Maybe someone has more experience with this library then I do.

The documentation can be found at https://github.com/bear/python-twitter

Comment: May be there is no follower with that `user-id`, and what does count supposed to do here? I mean you have already provided the user-id!

Comment: Count indicates the number of followers of that user you want returned. I used the same user id to query their tweets